# Re-index a list to nested map in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a variables of type `var students = List<StudentData>`. I need to create a map with the following structure: `Map<String, Map<Int, StudentData>>`.

`StudentData` has information like: studentID, classId, courseA, courseB, courseC etc.

So for the map would be the following: `Map<studentID, Map <classId, StudentData>>`. Meaning that for every student, I need a map of his `classId` and all the information.
How can I achieve this using kotlin ?

```
            var indexByCourse = Map<String, Map<Int, StudentData>>
            students.forEach {
                student -> indexByCourse.getOrPut(student.studentID, {mutableSetOf()}.add(??)
                    }
```

Not sure how to approach this problem. Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below way to map classId with it's corresponding information.

```
fun testFunction() {
        //for holding student data
        val students = ArrayList<StudentData>()
        students.add(StudentData(1, 10, "course a", "course 3"))
        students.add(StudentData(2, 11, "course b", "course 6"))
        students.add(StudentData(3, 12, "course c", "course 2"))
        students.add(StudentData(4, 13, "course d", "course 5"))

        //For holding course
        val indexByCourse = hashMapOf<Int, HashMap<Int, StudentData>>()

        students.forEachIndexed { index, studentData ->
            val studentSubData = hashMapOf(studentData.classId to studentData)
            indexByCourse[studentData.studentID] = studentSubData
        }

        //Fetch the student data based on studentID
        println(indexByCourse[3])

    }
```

and `StudentData` class for holding the values

```
data class StudentData(var studentID: Int, var classId: Int, var courseA: String, var courseB: String)
```

Comment: Thank you!! And if I were to want to map multiple studentData to the same courseId, `hashMapOf<Int, HashMap<Int, StudentData>>()`, would I be able to use the same approach by appending to the nested list instead of assigning the hash map?

Comment: @JennyJoy yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
data class StudentData(
  val studentID: String,
  val classId: Int,
  val courseA: String? = "",
  val courseB: String? = "",
  val courseC: String? = ""
)

val students = listOf(
  StudentData("1", 100, "Course 1"),
  StudentData("2", 100, "Course 1", "Course 2", "Course 3"),
  StudentData("3", 100, "Course 2", "Course 3"),
  StudentData("4", 200, "Course 1", "Course 3", "Course 3"),
  StudentData("5", 200, "Course 1", "Course 2")
)

val result = students
  .groupBy { studentData -> studentData.studentID }
  .map { (studentID, values) ->
    studentID to values
      .groupBy { studentData -> studentData.classId }
      .map { (classId, values) -> classId to values.first() }
      .toMap()
  }
  .toMap()

result.forEach(::println)
```

Output:

```
1={100=StudentData(studentID=1, classId=100, courseA=Course 1, courseB=, courseC=)}
2={100=StudentData(studentID=2, classId=100, courseA=Course 1, courseB=Course 2, courseC=Course 3)}
3={100=StudentData(studentID=3, classId=100, courseA=Course 2, courseB=Course 3, courseC=)}
4={200=StudentData(studentID=4, classId=200, courseA=Course 1, courseB=Course 3, courseC=Course 3)}
5={200=StudentData(studentID=5, classId=200, courseA=Course 1, courseB=Course 2, courseC=)}
```